# Como abrir una imagen en una ventana

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un chat donde se pueden enviar mensajes y enviar archivos.

Así que le estoy modificando para que en vez de si es imagen no salga el nombre nomas, y me muestre la imagen en el chat. Pero cuando quiero hacerle click a la imagen me carga otra pagina y no es lo quiero. Que al darle click se abra otra ventana.

```
function openImage() {
    window.open('ruta/a/la/imagen.jpg', 'Imagen', 'width=500, height=500');
}
```

estaba probando esa función pero no me funciona por como tengo codigo.

```
function Seguimientos(id) {
        //_Create
        const format1 = "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"

        console.log('seguimientos');

        //var URL = '@Url.Action("SeguimientosPorSolicitudId", "SolicitudSeguimientos")' + '/' + id;
        var URL = '/SolicitudSeguimientos/SeguimientosPorSolicitudId' + '/' + id;
        console.log('url ' + URL);
        var card = "";
        $.getJSON({
            url: URL,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                $.each(data.seguimientos, function (i, o) {

                card += "<div class='direct-chat-msg'>";
                card += "<div class='direct-chat-infos clearfix'>";
                card += "<span class='direct-chat-name float-left'>"

                if (o.AgenteId != 0) {
                    card += o.Agente.Nombre;
                }
                else {
                    card += o.Contacto.Nombre;
                }
                card += "</span>";
                card += "<span class='direct-chat-timestamp float-right'>" + moment(o.Fecha).format(format1) + "</span>";
                card += "</div>";
                if (o.Mensaje == null) {
                    card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'></div>";
                }
                else {
                    card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'>" + o.Mensaje.replaceAll("\n", "<br>")
                    if (o.Mensaje != null && o.Archivos != null && o.Archivos != "undefined") {

                        //card += "<br>" + o.Archivos; + "<br>"
                        card += "<br>";
                        //card += "<div class='row'>";
                        var nameFiles = new Array();
                        nameFiles = o.Archivos.split(',');
                        console.log('namesFiles: ' + nameFiles);

                        for (let i = 0; i < nameFiles.length; i++) {
                            console.log('nameFiles[i]: ' + nameFiles[i]);

                            var name = o.SolicitudId + "-" + nameFiles[i];
                            var path = "/Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name;

                            const openImage = () => {
                                window.open(path, 'Imagen');
                            };

                            card += "<div>";
                            if (nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")) {
                                card += "<a data-gallery='manual2' href='" + path + "'>";
                                card += "<img src='" + path + "' style='width:150px;height:150px;text-align:center; border-radius: 5px;' target='_blank'>";
                                card += "</a>";
                            }
                            else {
                                card += "<a href='./../../Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name + "' target='_blank'>" + name + "</a>";
                            }
                            card += "</div>";

                            //card += "<a href='./../../Content/Images/Seguimientos/" + name + "' target='_blank'>" + name + "</a>";
                        }
                    }
                    + "</div>";
                }

                card += "</div>";

                });
                var parser = new DOMParser;
                var dom = parser.parseFromString(card, 'text/html');

                console.log('card length: ' + card.length);
                if (card.length > 0) {
                    console.log('hay seguimientos');
                document.querySelectorAll('[id="mensajes"]').forEach(element => {
                    element.innerHTML = card;
                    SeguimientosVistos(id);
                })
                console.log('innetHTML done');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('no hay seguimientos');
                    document.querySelectorAll('[id="mensajes"]').forEach(element => {
                        element.innerHTML = "<h1>No hay seguimientos</h1>";
                    })
                }
            },
```

Con esto cargo los mensajes que tengo apuntando a un modal que tengo. Y con los que muestro las imágenes en el chat, es if que tengo.

```
if (nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") || nameFiles[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")) {
                                card += "<a data-gallery='manual2' href='" + path + "'>";
                                card += "<img src='" + path + "' style='width:150px;height:150px;text-align:center; border-radius: 5px;' target='_blank'>";
                                card += "</a>";
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero te sirve en lugar de **Image** coloca como quieres que se abra la ventana, pues ese es el target del método `window.open()`:

```js
function abreVentana() {
  window.open("http://via.placeholder.com/300", "_blank", "width=400,height=400");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="abreVentana()">Abrir imagen!</button>
```

estos son los posibles valores(existen otros estos son los principales) para el **target** de ventana a abrir

```
Value   Description
_blank  URL es cargada en una nueva ventana o tab.(por omisión va esta)
_parent URL es cargada en el contener padre.
_self   URL carga en la ventana actual
```

Por lo tanto tu fucnion quedaría como:

```javascript
const openImage = () => {
    window.open(path, '_blank');//suponiendo quieres que abra en una nueva tab
};
```

[Mayor info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: No sabía mucho sobre los values del target, gracias.